# Improving a python code reading files

Tags: python

I wrote a python script to treat text files. 
The input is a file with several lines. At the beginning of each line, there is a number (1, 2, 3... , n). Then an empty line and the last line on which some text is written.

I need to read through this file to delete some lines at the beginning and some in the end (say number 1 to 5 and then number 78 to end). I want to write the remaining lines on a new file (in a new directory) and renumber the first numbers written on these lines (in my example, 6 would become 1, 7 2 etc.)

I wrote the following:

```
def treatFiles(oldFile,newFile,firstF, startF, lastF):

    % firstF is simply an index
    % startF corresponds to the first line I want to keep
    % lastF corresponds to the last line I want to keep
    numberFToDeleteBeginning = int(startF) - int(firstF)
    with open(oldFile) as old, open(newFile, 'w') as new:
        countLine = 0
        for line in old:
            countLine += 1
            if countLine <= numberFToDeleteBeginning:
                pass
            elif countLine > int(lastF) - int(firstF):
                pass
            elif line.split(',')[0] == '\n':
                newLineList = line.split(',')
                new.write(line)
            else:        
                newLineList = [str(countLine - numberFToDeleteBeginning)] + line.split(',')
                del newLineList[1]
                newLine = str(newLineList[0])
                for k in range(1, len(newLineList)):
                    newLine = newLine + ',' + str(newLineList[k])    
                new.write(newLine)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
      from sys import argv
      import os

      os.makedirs('treatedFiles')
      new = 'treatedFiles/' + argv[1]
      treatFiles(argv[1], argv[2], newFile, argv[3], argv[4], argv[5])
```

My code works correctly but is far too slow (I have files of about 10Gb to treat and it's been running for hours).

Does anyone know how I can improve it?

Comment: You are trying to analyze 10Gb of txt? Unless you have a super computer, you should expect this to take weeks, even with efficient code. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SamyBencherif: That's not true at all.

Comment: @Samy I analyse several such files most days.

Comment: Really? I guess I overestimated that. 

also I did the math, which yields a seemingly more accurate prediction: 10gb = 10 billion chars, my computer can do about 100,000 simple operations per second, based on that it would take 10000 seconds (assuming each character has an operation applied to it) to analyse 10 gb, which is **about 3 hours**.

Comment: @SamyBencherif: I processed a 14GB file with Python two days ago in about 30 minutes, so your prediction isn't really accurate. The bottleneck is probably going to be the read/write speeds of your hard drive.

Comment: @Blender That's a good point, I was basing this off of how many times my computer could evaluate 1+1 in a second. There are too many other variables though, I have never actually processed something that large.

Comment: @Samy Unless your computer is ~20 years old, it should be able to do **hundreds of billions** of simple operations per second (in the 100 GFLOPS range). That’s at least six orders of magnitude more than what you estimated. Of course just *reading* the file is much slower, but not nearly as slow as you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get rid of the `for` loop in the middle and the expensive `.split()`:

```
from itertools import islice

def treatFiles(old_file, new_file, index, start, end):
    with open(old_file, 'r') as old, open(new_file, 'w') as new:
        sliced_file = islice(old, start - index, end - index)

        for line_number, line in enumerate(sliced_file, start=1):
            number, rest = line.split(',', 1)

            if number == '\n':
                new.write(line)
            else:
                new.write(str(line_number) + ',' + rest)
```

Also, convert your three numerical arguments to integers before passing them into the function:

```
treatFiles(argv[1], argv[2], newFile, int(argv[3]), int(argv[4]), int(argv[5]))
```

Comment: I just have to replace `new.write(line_number + ',' + rest)` by `new.write(str(line_number) + ',' + rest)` and it works. thanks!